# Stack Exchange Filter is not working, how to fix it?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

Whenever I want to answer some questions on Stack Overflow, I rely on this [FILTER](https://stackexchange.com/filters/26378/sql) that I've made in Stack Exchange.

But now, it gives me the following error every time:

> Oops! An error occurred while fetching questions for this filter.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded,
> and developers have been notified

---

This has been going on for quite some time (more than 2 weeks) and that's why I decided to post it here, what should I do?

Comment: I'm getting the error as well.

Comment: I don't have the error on `hot` and `activity`. Only on `newest` or `no answers`.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'm only getting the error on the `no answers` tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange has outgrown our current filters architecture, so many large filters (and even some not-so-large ones) are timing out and resulting in this error. We're working on a new implementation to fix these issues.

**edit**: We made some optimizations to our SQL query so largish queries such as this one are finishing in a reasonable amount of time now.